# How to get html, css and js all in one get with akka http?

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, akka-http, twirl

I'm trying to serve my html, css and js with akka http:

```
path("") {
  get {
    getFromResourceDirectory("home")
    complete(HttpEntity(ContentTypes.`text/html(UTF-8)`, home.render().toString()))
  }
}
```

`home.render()` is a twirl template that renders:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="home.css"> 
        <script src="home.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

The html loads without problem except for the css and js files, this is my dir structure:

[image]
and this error in chrome:

```
GET http://localhost:8080/home.js net::ERR_ABORTED
localhost/:5 GET http://localhost:8080/home.css net::ERR_ABORTED
```

Comment: Did you find any better solution? If yes, I would much appreciate if you could share it.

Answer (score 2):

In my project I solved it with `getFromResource(path)` method and **additional route** for resources:

```
val resourcePrefix = "pages"

get {
    pathSingleSlash {
      getFromResource("home.html")
    } ~
    path(resourcePrefix / Remaining) { resource =>
      getFromResource(resource)
    }
}
```

In your template file you would refer to resources like this:

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/pages/home.css"> 
    <script src="/pages/home.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: oh sorry man have been in holliday will check it once i arrive home today ;)

Comment: still not working I added `        <link rel="stylesheet" href="home/home.css">
        <script src="home/home.js"></script>` can you see what am I missing?

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding. According to my example it should be `<link rel="stylesheet" href="/pages/home/home.css">` and `<script src="/pages/home/home.js"></script>`